# Resolve naming collisions with EXIF SubSecTime tags

Tags: metadata, sony-alpha

I've started managing my pictures with DigiKam. In order to avoid naming conflicts when importing pictures from multiple camera's in the same album, I wanted to rename al my pictures to contain the date and time of shooting.

At first I used a naming scheme that contained the date and the time as follows:

```
yyyyMMdd_hhmmss
```

However, if multiple pictures were taken at the same second (different or same camera), there are still naming conflicts. That's why I wanted to include the milliseconds as well. However, it turns out my Sony Alpha 6000 does not record the EXIF SubSecTime when taking a picture and I can't seem to find a setting that enables this. My LG Nexus 5 does record this.

Does anyone know if this can be enabled? Or do most camera's not record sub second time? If not, does anyone know a good alternative to avoid naming conflicts or how to you handle this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why renaming in this specific format ? Can you just tag with yyyMMdd_camera_automaticNumberIncrement ?

Comment: Sounds like you're dropping the original filename - if you keep things as IMG1234-20161009_131423.CR2 or similar, it seems pretty unlikely to me you'll get any conflicts.

Comment: @Olivier Using an automatic increment is indeed a gooed alternative.

Comment: @PhilipKendall The problem with that is if I collect pictures from multiple people, their camera's might also use the IMGxxx format.

Comment: @PieterV Sure - but unless you're collecting *lots* of people, what are the chances that two people will be shooting on cameras which use the same image name format *and* produce the same file number *and* do so at the same second? Seems pretty unlikely to me. Naively, it's a birthday paradox problem, so you'd need ~ sqrt(10000) = 100 photos *per second* before it's an issue.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Yeah I know, chances are very small. Although, I already have a few pictures myself that were taken within the same second (e.g. in a burst)

Answer (score 1):

**Auto increment**

Unless you have to use this specific format, I would suggest using some form of auto increment when renaming your files.

Something like yyyyMMdd_cameraCodeName_### should do the trick (###=increment number).